# Installation failed for point cloud library on Windows

Tags: point-cloud-library, failed-installation, openni

I am trying to install PCL by this easy [installer](http://unanancyowen.com/en/pcl18/). However, I am getting an error while it tries to install OpenNI, [error message 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZlPUO.jpg), because of which it fails to install PrimeSense Sensor [error message 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1yJsb.jpg). Has anybody else encountered this problem? If yes, how did you resolve it?
Thanks!

Comment: Do you need OpenNI? According to your link it's an optional. Have you tried the official PCL windows installers from http://www.pointclouds.org/downloads/windows.html ?

Comment: I get an error if I don't install openNI, I don't know why. I'll try to reinstall all of it again and get back